# Thread.sleep() doesn't block mainThread in coroutine in Android activity lifecycle?

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, java-threads

I tested this code of an Android activity, the log shows that Thread.sleep() actually didn't block the mainThread to run the onStart and onResume of the lifecycle.

I understand if I use suspend function like [delay](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/delay.html) will have this result.
But I assumed **Thread.sleep() would **pause the mainThread**** to run lifecycle's onStart() and onResume() for a while (1000ms in this example) ?

```
override fun onCreate() {
    Log.d("TEST", "onCreate")

    GlobalScope.launch {
        Log.d("TEST", "Before Sleep")
        Thread.sleep(1000L)
        Log.d("TEST", "After Sleep")
    }
}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    Log.d("TEST", "onStart")
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    Log.d("TEST", "onResume")
}
```

The log

```
09:12:04.298 10139-10139/com.example D/TEST: onCreate
09:12:04.456 10139-10180/com.example D/TEST: Before Sleep
09:12:04.459 10139-10139/com.example D/TEST: onStart
09:12:04.461 10139-10139/com.example D/TEST: onResume
09:12:05.457 10139-10180/com.example D/TEST: After Sleep
```

Answer (score 1):

You should know about `GlobalScope` as the document said, and it not block your `MainThread`

> Launches a new coroutine without blocking the current thread

> If the context does not have any dispatcher nor any other ContinuationInterceptor, then Dispatchers.Default is used

If you want to block inside current `Activity` you can try `lifecycleScope` instead

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
        Log.d("TEST", "Before Sleep")
        Thread.sleep(1000L)
        Log.d("TEST", "After Sleep")
}
```

or put Thread.sleep() outside of coroutine to block main thread

```
GlobalScope.launch {
    Log.d("TEST", "Before Sleep")
    delay(1000L)
    Log.d("TEST", "After Sleep")
}
Thread.sleep(2000L)
```

Comment: Yes. I used "lifecycleScope" instead had the result I had expected. Thanks.

Does "Dispatchers.Unconfined" lead Thread.sleep() to freeze another worker thread ?

Comment: Sure, it affects another worker thread. You should know about what lifecycleScope actual thread running. it's Main.immediate

Comment: Cong Hai, thanks again. I tested GlobalScope with Dispatcher.Main.immediate. It seemed that it didn't behave like lifecycleScope. The logic inside the withContext(Dispatchers.Main.immediate) {}  was performed after onResume was finished.